# Duplicate data fetched for a particular ID

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net

There is a data with different ids and it contains sub id's inside it. For eg. ID-abcd, sub ID-abcd1, abcd2. But for a specific id, the sub ID is fetching same data as the parent ID. For eg: ID- abcd, sub ID- abcd.

I think there is some problem in my loop but can't think of any resolution.

Code of loop:

```
 Private Sub PrintTabs(tableSuffix As String, idSO As String, vol As String, ByRef myConnection As SqlConnection)

        Dim tabColor As String = ""
        Dim numTab As Integer
        Dim mycVolTab As New SqlCommand("SELECT QI_MATERIAL,QIV_ID,QPSOPROD_VOLID " &
                                          " FROM QUO_OFFER_PROD_VOL " &
                                          " LEFT OUTER JOIN QUO_OFFER_PRODUCT ON QIV_PRODID = QI_ID " &
                                          " LEFT OUTER JOIN QUO_OFFER_PROD_SO_PROD" & tableSuffix & " ON QPSOPROD_VOLID = QIV_ID " &
                                          " WHERE QPSOPROD_SOID = @QIV_ID ORDER BY QI_MATERIAL ", myConnection)
        mycVolTab.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QIV_ID", idSO)
        Dim myrVolTab As SqlDataReader = mycVolTab.ExecuteReader

        Dim i = 0
        While myrVolTab.Read
            If vol = myrVolTab("QIV_ID") Then
                tabColor = ""
                numTab = i
            Else
                tabColor = "background-color:#c0c0c0 !important;cursor:pointer;border-color:#c0c0c0"
            End If
            DIV_TABS.InnerHtml &= "<div class='fleft boxSectionTit2' style='width:auto !important;margin-left:10px;" & tabColor & "' onclick=viewSO(" & idSO & "," & myrVolTab("QPSOPROD_VOLID") & ")>" & myrVolTab(0) & "</div>"
            i += 1
        End While

        myrVolTab.Close()
    End Sub
```

In the image, above output is of the incorrect id showing two values. Below id is correct showing single value.

[image]

Comment: Not sure I'm really understanding the issue here.  Could you perhaps update your question with some real example source data?